# Turn heroku app into Idle manually

Tags: heroku

I want to turn my app into idling mode on Heroku. All I want is to trace my timeout app exception and fix it. 
I installed Relic but it is too complicated to make it work. So I think I just need to fix this error on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot "idle" your app manually.
You can scale it down though:

> heroku ps:scale web=0

Comment: Will it gave me the same error as I get when my app is in idle?

Comment: From the client, yes, you will get a 503. From your app logs though, it won't be the same error. See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes